# Elastic search: allow/find objects with missing nested fields/empty arrays?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to use 2 bool should filters together: one which returns objects containing any `event_dates.starts_at` values within a date range, eg:

```
"event_dates": [
   {
      "starts_at": "2016-12-04T08:00:00+07:00"
   },
   {
      "starts_at": "2016-12-11T08:00:00+07:00"
   }
]
```

(works fine by itself), and another which allows objects containing no `event_dates.starts_at` fields at the same time, eg:

```
"event_dates": []
```

(using a missing query for this, but seems to cancel out the effect of the first filter and just returns everything in my database)

below is the query I have so far:

```
{  
   "query":{  
      "filtered":{  
         "filter":{  
            "and":[  
               {  
                  "bool":{  
                     "should":[  
                        {  
                           "nested":{  
                              "path":"event_dates",
                              "filter":{  
                                 "range":{  
                                    "event_dates.starts_at":{  
                                       "gte":"20161125",
                                       "lte":null,
                                       "format":"basic_date"
                                    }
                                 }
                              }
                           }
                        },
                        {  
                           "missing":{  
                              "field":"event_dates.starts_at"
                           }
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

(there may be some unnecessary bits since I've extracted this from a larger query). Would anyone know where I am going wrong with this? Have tried specifying the missing filter as a nested path as well, but couldn't get that to work either...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "and": [
          {
            "nested": {
              "path": "event_dates",
              "filter": {
                "bool": {
                  "should": [
                    {
                      "range": {
                        "event_dates.starts_at": {
                          "gte": "20161125",
                          "lte": null,
                          "format": "basic_date"
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "missing": {
                        "field": "event_dates.starts_at"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```